# SSRS IIF condition error

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to return a green YES if equal to 1, else return a red NO. Which means it equals 0. I found this which I think is helpful but can't figure out how to piece it together.[SSRS - Conditional Text Formatting (Expressions using Switch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068048/ssrs-conditional-text-formatting-expressions-using-switch)

The below gives me an error

```
IIF(Fields!SurveyCompleted.Value = 1, "Green", "Red")
```

Error   4   [rsFieldReferenceAmbiguous] The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox12’ refers directly to the field ‘SurveyCompleted’ without specifying a dataset aggregate.  When the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.

I got the following to accidentally work to change the text when trying to change the color.

```
=First(IIF(Fields!UniqueReportRequests.Value = 1, "Yes", "No"),"RawCompletionScore")
```

How can I combine both to change the color and text? The color expression needs the dataset "RawCompletionScore" declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this ..

```
=IIF(First(Fields!SurveyCompleted.Value, "RawCompletionScore") = 1, "Green", "Red")
```

**Modified:**

On your TextBox ..

[image]

Right mouse click and select Expression.

Enter your expression ..

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!UniqueReportRequests.Value, "RawCompletionScore") = 1, "Yes", "No")
```

In the TextBox Properties, set your Background Color ..

[image]

```
=IIF(First(Fields!SurveyCompleted.Value, "RawCompletionScore") = 1, "Green", "Red")
```

Comment: This changes the text to "Green" for me. How can I change the color to green? Or even better, change the color to green AND text?

Comment: Modified the answer as this is what I believe you are looking for.

Comment: This makes sense but now I'm getting this error `Error 4 [rsFieldReferenceAmbiguous] The Color expression for the text box ‘Textbox12’ refers directly to the field ‘SurveyCompleted’ without specifying a dataset aggregate.  When the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope. 
`

Comment: Based on the error message you may be missing First() function around the field. Please show your code if you are still having an issue.

Comment: It was still picking up a lingering color expression that I deleted but somehow still existed. Thanks for the help!